# Adding three integer sparse matrices is very slow. Adding only two is fast

Tags: performance-tuning, bugs, sparse-arrays

**Bug introduced in 9.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.0**

---

Adding more than two sparse matrices *in one step* in Mathematica 9 is very slow (in fact I couldn't even wait for it to finish).

Here's an example.  Let's generate a large sparse matrix:

```
am = AdjacencyMatrix@RandomGraph[{25000, 50000}];

am + am; // Timing (* very fast *)

(am + am) + am; // Timing (* very fast *)

am + am + am; // Timing (* so slow I didn't wait for it to finish *)
```

Can anyone reproduce this?  I used Mathematica 9.0.0 on OS X.  Mathematica 8 does not have this problem.

Does anyone have any ideas what may be going wrong here?

Comment: I can reproduce this on Mathematica 9.0.0 (OS X)

Comment: Two people can reproduce it so tagging as bug.

Comment: With V8 `RandomGraph[{25000, 50000}]` returns and error.

Comment: I am using V8.0.4 OS X 10.6.8 and am unable to evaluate `am`!

Comment: @Mike Precisely what error do you get?  I originally had `RandomGraph[{50000, 100000}]` but I has to reduce the size to half of that to test on v8 as v8 returned a `len32` error for the bigger graph.  `RandomGraph[{25000, 50000}]` does work fine on 8 here, and the addition does not have the performance problem it has on 9.

Comment: `RandomGraph::dist: "A graph distribution is expected at position 1 in RandomGraph[{25000,50000}]."`

Comment: @Mike That's unusual!  Are you sure you have 8.0.4?  I have `$Version === "8.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 22, 2012)"`.  What if you try smaller graphs, e.g. `RandomGraph[{10,20}]`?  EDIT: [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FR5ur.png)

Comment: Yes it is 8.0.4 but I am on a 32 bit machine (that is why I do not have 9 on this machine) which is probably the only difference. Smaller graphs are fine.

Comment: Reproduced in M9 and agree it is a bug. Can also reproduce @MikeHoneychurch's bug in 32-bit M8.0.4 only (but did not try 8.0.1 or 8.0.0). At least this one seems to have been fixed in M9, since 32- and 64-bit versions now behave in the same way.

Comment: @OleksandrR. V9 doesn't run on 32 bit does it?? i.e. I was unable to install V9 on my computer (32 bit one i am using right now) -- I was told it is 64 bit only.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch don't know, sorry. I'm using a 64-bit OS, so had no installation issues... I just started the 32-bit M9 kernel to do this test.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have reported this as a bug. Having said that, here is some more info:

Note that when you use:

```
am = AdjacencyMatrix@RandomGraph[{25000, 50000}];//N
```

you do not see the issue. So this is only an integer sparse array issue. What happened until V8 internally is that there is a loop for adding each sparse array as a binary operation. E.g. something like:

```
res = Plus[Plus[sp1,sp2],sp3]
```

In version 9 this has been changed to use var args. In essence what you do with using parentheses is to enforce the old behavior. The reason this was changed is that the var args form of the code is faster and uses less memory:

```
am = (AdjacencyMatrix@RandomGraph[{2500, 5000}]) // N;
MaxMemoryUsed[am + am; // Timing] (*very fast*)
MaxMemoryUsed[(am + am) + am; // Timing] (*very fast*)
MaxMemoryUsed[
 am + am + am; // Timing] (*so slow I didn't wait for it to finish*)
```

So for now you can either convert with `N` if that is possible, or use the parentheses.

Comment: A side comment, this one argument form of `MaxMemoryUsed` is undocumented and I didn't know about it.  It looks very useful.

Comment: For those who are not familiar with C: "var args" refers to a variadic function defined using [`stdarg.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h).

Comment: @Szabolcs, yes, that's new. The developer how does memory allocation did that for me - I need this all the time, it's so useful. It will count all allocations that go through the internal allocator. But the usual caveat for undocumented stuff applies here too. If you find issues with it let me know.