# Is it possible to find the size of a variable in a notebook?

Tags: export, variable, size

I have a fairly large a list of matrices `matsLst`, which takes about 15 minutes to compute (but computes successfully each time).  I can test in the notebook that the computation has happened correctly.

But when I try to write it to disk using

```
Export["matsLst.mx", matsLst];
```

the command takes hours to run.  The last time the export happened successfully, it took three hours.  Right now, it's still going on two hours.  I know that disk space should not be a problem, because I have about 40 GB available on my disk.

But is there a way for me to find out just how large a particular variable is before I choose to write it or not?  (I mean, the whole point of writing an MX file is to save the computation time later.)

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47491).

Comment: Does DumpSave take the same amount of time?

Answer (score 5):

You could try `ByteCount[expr]`. According to the documentation it gives the number of bytes used internally to store the expression.